# Symfony 4: Accessing Form Data without Nested For Loop

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony-forms

I would like to access the entities submitted by a form without having to use a nested for loop. Currently, in order to access the entity objects I am doing the following:

```
$courses = $form->getData();

foreach ($courses as $course) {
    foreach ($course as $c) {
        //do logic on entity $c
    }
}
```

Form builder class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('courses', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Course::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($organization) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('course')
                    ->orderBy('course.semester', 'ASC');
            },
        ]);
    }
```

How can I structure the form such that the entities would be accessible with a single for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `getData()` is returning *all* form *fields*, but since you seem to have only one, it is working as "you expect" but just by accident. If you decided to add more fields, a `user` field for instance, at some point the `$course` variable will hold a `User` entity. It'll be more clear if you rewrite this as `$fieldData = $form->getData()`, and now you can think of it as an array keyed by `fieldName`.

You should be able to get just the `Course` collection (the specific field) by using:

```
$courses = $form->get('courses')->getData();  
// Or using PropertyAccess: $form['courses']->getData()

foreach ($courses as $course) {
// ...
}
```